# Debian7, date and time formats to Hungarian

Tags: linux, debian

how can I change (only) the date and time formats to Hungarian on a Debian7 (but the language I want to keep English)...

I've tried to change like this:

/etc/defaults/locale

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
LC_TIME="hu_HU" (or "hu_HU.UTF-8" or hu_HU.UTF-8)
```

... but the date time format remains...

```
root@debian:~# date
Fri Mar 21 13:07:48 CET 2014
```

... but the charset changed somehow, because if I start mc the border lines looks terrible, and if I remove LC_TIME line from /etc/defaults/locale the lines are fine again...

any ideas?

root@debian:~# locale

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What's the output of `locale`? Is it a supported locale? Does it show up in `locale -a`? If not, `dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Comment: hi, 'dpkg-reconfigure locales' solved... THX! please make an answer, and I will accept and rate it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/etc/default/locale` file is typically read upon login (see `/etc/pam.d/login`).

So, you generally need to logout and login again for it to take effect.

`locale` alone gives you the current settings (based on the value of all those environment variables (`LC_*`, `LANG`, `LANGUAGE`...).

In order to be able to use a `locale`, the locale has to be compiled into `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`. On a typical Debian system, only a few locales are compiled into that by default to save resources.

You can change the list of supported locales by running:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

as root.

Comment: unfortunately I have no right (yet) to rise the value. so I can only accept yout answer... THX again